# How can I configure tortoiseHg to use gvimdiff instead of kdiff3?

Tags: vim, mercurial, tortoisehg

Setting it globally in "settings" seems to be ignored (double clicking a snapshot still opens kdiff3).

[image]

Comment: The `-d` should be inside the quotes, I think.

Comment: no experience with tortoisehg, I just config vimdiff as diff tool in `.hgrc`

Comment: @romainl that doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: @Kent since I'm forced into a GUI situation in windows, I have to use gvim.

Comment: I had a quick look first and thought you were using the same appl that I use, but you don't (deleted my answer). Have a look at http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/manual/1.0/common.html#adding-tools

Comment: This answer doesn't work with newer versions of TortoiseHg, see this link for a possible solution: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergingWithVim